# python implementation of t-sne with images

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, descriptor

I have a list of descriptors (4096 floats) and images associated to them. 
I would like to run t-sne on these descriptors and show in the plot the corresponding images.

Currently my script is something like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import time 
import pandas as pd
#from ggplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

n_components = 4096
table = []

with open(os.path.join("folder", "fulldescriptors.txt")) as f:
    for descriptor in f.readlines():
        d = [float(i) for i in descriptor.split(" ")]

        table.append(d) 

n_sne = len(table)

df = pd.DataFrame(table)

time_start = time.time()
tsne = TSNE(n_components=3, verbose=1, perplexity=40, n_iter=50000)
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(df)


plt.scatter(tsne_results[:,0] , tsne_results[:,1])
plt.show()
```

How can I replace the points with the images in the plot?